# Currency Rate cron job doesnt work

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, crontab

Since most people were having problem with Webservicex of `Magento 1.9.2`, I am using the `Fixer.io` to update my currency rates. When I do it manually it works like a charm and I have enabled the scheduled update on `System > Configuration > Currency Setup` but for some reason it doesn't seem to be updating them through cron daily so I have to do it manually all the time.

In my crontab I have the following line of code to run the cron:

```
*/5 * * * * wget -O /dev/null -q http://www.example.com/cron.php > /dev/null
```

Of course example is replaced with my proper website domain, any suggestions on why its not working as intended or a good way to check if the cron job is getting executed correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: yup, used https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler